# how to use builtin Identity function use

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

i want to use builtin identity class and methods for creating user and get token from it for authentication i spend 7 8 hours in this but not success any idea how to use this
i am using Entity Framework Code first how to create use .. authenticate user from email and password please anyone help me this highly appreciated 
 .net core 2.1 and 2.2

```
  private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = null;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;


async Task<bool> CreateIdentityUserAsync(string email, int userid, string password)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "abc@gmail.com",
                Email = "abc@gmail.com",
                OrgaId = 1,
                RegisteredUserId = 1,
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "s@r@hi123);

            return result.Succeeded;
        }][1]][1]

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
```

Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
Invalid column name 'ConcurrencyStamp'.
Invalid column name 'LockoutEnd'.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the defination for `ApplicationUser`? Was it inherited from `IdentityUser`?

Comment: yes it is......i edit my question add application user class

Comment: It seems ok, is there any demo or detail steps to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change your lines of:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = null;
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
```

to

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
```

Also you need to do dependency injection for them.